# how to use url routing in asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, asp.net-4.0

how i can use url routing in asp.net 4.0 . how it is possible in asp.net 4.0 ;

```
are you provide some demo code , sample project for it
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest starting by reading a blog post by The Gu: [URL Routing with ASP.NET 4 Web Forms (VS 2010 and .NET 4.0 Series)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

He has an introductory discussion with some good examples on the following topics:

- What is URL Routing?
- Mapping URLs using ASP.NET MVC
- Mapping URLs using ASP.NET Web Forms
- Retrieving URLs within an ASP.NET Web Form
- Handling PostBack Scenarios

Here is an example of using routing in Web Forms:
[image: Routing Web Forms Example]

Answer (score 0):

[URL Routing with ASP.NET 4 Web Forms (VS 2010 and .NET 4.0 Series)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) by Scott Guthrie.
[URL Routing with ASP.NET 4.0](http://aspalliance.com/1881_URL_Routing_with_ASPNET_40) by ASPAlliance.

Comment: i try it but i have a more confusion too how can i see any demo by a sample code project